# columnize jQuery - force columns to dont warp

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've used columnize plugin to make my long content into newspaper columns.

its look like this: [enter](http://impactweb.pl/columnize/)

problem is that I've used the same styles like here: [enter](http://jsfiddle.net/NPzsV/3/) to force divs to stay in one line.

They dont stay in line, its first problem, and 2nd is how to force those columns to have constant height.

I'm open for other solutions too. Need constan height, multi column, horizontal scrolling content page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the width of the document, and the height. Then based on those two begin to construct your elements. Decide how many columns you want which will determine their width. Since you state that height is constant, that is already taken care of. Use `overflow: auto;` to implement a scrollbar inside of the column to allow for horizontal scrolling if the content gets to large for the space.

Comment: I cant do so, becouse it would be implemented into blog theme, cant say how long content will be. But even considering that. You can zoom that website, or increase body width. Freaking odd things happens.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain an exact width with columnizer, and to scroll horizontally, just add a `height` property to the inputs, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/NPzsV/3/ and in sample 5 on the [documentation page](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

```
$('#a').columnize({width: 400, height: 500})
```

will do the trick